# Maximo Anywhere Customized drop down

Tags: maximo, maximo-anywhere

I am working in Maximo Anywhere 7.5.2 (Work Execution App). I need to add a dropdown based on my own values instead of creating a domain/lookup attribute in Maximo EAM. How to do it ?

I have seen "combobox" in app.xsd but no idea on adding it in app.xml. Pl help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah unfortunately we don't really expose or document this combobox in the app.xsd, we really only use it at this time dynamically in our specification attributes.  You should however give it a try, setting the attributes listed in the app.xsd from within a combobox nested in the groupitem (like other attribute types)